# Optimization Models and the chicken-and-egg problem

Tags: optimization, reference-request, mathematical-modeling, numerical-optimization, time-series

I have started working with optimization models to minimize the total generation costs of electricity in a system. The basic idea in this model is to minimize the overall system cost given a certain level of demand. I want to use this model to forecast costs in the future, which means that I have to make some assumptions about the demand and how it will increase or decrease. The problem is that this is a typical chicken-and-egg situation. If I assume an increase in demand, the system cost will be higher, thereby reducing the demand.

With time series data, this problem can be addressed using a lagged variable. So, I was wondering if there is a way to apply this concept to optimization models. How would you approach this problem? Can you recommend some articles or books addressing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are looking at the wrong things. It is trivial to minimize cost: just shut the place down and leave the demand unfilled. What you need to do is maximize profit. You use your modelling of cost by demand to model the profit by demand for a given unit price. Then you use past data to estimate how demand changes with unit price. Combining this information with the profit function gives you a model of profit as a function of just unit price, which is what you maximize to find your price point. If you manage to do it right, your production will exactly match demand.